# Can Azure Bastion Host be configured for unattended ssh logins?

Tags: azure, bastion

Can bastion hosts be setup for unattended ssh logins?

I've not been able to find anything in the documentation. All I see is that a user goes to the Azure portal and connects through the portual UI over 443. Nothing to indicate that public SSH(22) access is available.

Possible use cases:

- DevOps Pipeline
- Cron Job Script
- Scheduled Backup script

Comment: Your point of entry to SSH is the Azure Portal, don't think that's be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, Bastion is purely a portal based UI feature, there is no API you can use to programmatically get SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using Bastion Native Client it is possible to create a tunnel from your local machine using PowerShell.

What I am not so sure about is if this can be done over DevOps Pipelines, which I would need personally, since the tunnel locks the current prompt and forces you to use another window for the actual ssh or scp.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-connect-vm-ssh-windows

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/connect-native-client-windows

EDIT: I just found the `az vm invoke-command` command which to some degree let's me replace my need for ssh, which also is pipeline friendly. Scp I have not found a simple replacement for.